# How do I bind inputs to observables in an observableArray?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an object (which is observable) and it has keys, each of which is observable.  One of those keys is an array that contains other observables.

I want to be able to modify these values using HTML input fields.  What came to my mind to do was to simply foreach through the observable array, and do value/textInput bindings to the inputs to modify them.

However, when modifying the text inputs - the value in the original doesn't change!  Am I doing something wrong?  Why aren't the bound values updating the way I expect?

I've broken down what I'm doing into a more generic version: http://jsfiddle.net/veqr2q6q/

```html
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <div class="line-container" data-bind="foreach: {data: text, as: 'line'}">
        <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: line" /><br />
    </div>
    <h2>Hello,</h2>
    <ul data-bind='foreach: {data: text, as: "line"}'>
        <li data-bind="text: line"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.text = ko.observableArray([
        ko.observable(first),
        ko.observable(last)
    ])
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this scenario you want to use `$rawData`.   I updated your fiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/veqr2q6q/2/

```
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <div class="line-container" data-bind="foreach: text">
        <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: $rawData" /><br />
    </div>
    <h2>Hello,</h2>
    <ul data-bind='foreach: {data: text, as: "line"}'>
        <li data-bind="text: line"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As referenced in the [Knockout JS docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

> Usually [`$rawData`] will be the same as `$data`, but if the view model provided to Knockout is wrapped in an observable, `$data` will be the unwrapped view model, and `$rawData` will be the observable itself.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  My learning of KO has been ad-hoc so I didn't even know about `$rawData` or even `textInput` until just this week.